# is it possible to give html5 datalist trigger on given string length?

Tags: html, html-datalist

is it possible to give html5 datalist trigger on given string length?

```
<input list="tagLookup" id="tag" name="tag" type="text" placeholder="+ add custom tag" autocomplete=off triggerOn="3">
<datalist id="tagLookup">
  <option value="aaaa">
  <option value="bbbb">
  <option value="cccc">
</datalist>
```

Would like to show suggestion on 3 characters entered by user.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any property that allows you do do this with just HTML. With javascript you could enforce this behavior. The best way seems to be to remove the `list=` attribute from the `input` as long as you don't need the datalist.

Here's a jQuery example that does what you need:

I added a `data-list` attribute with a copy of the `list` attribute so that it's easier to restore it after more than 2 characters were typed.

```js
$('input[list]').on('input', function(e) {
  var input = $(e.target),
      datalist = input.attr('data-list');

  if(input.val().length < 3) {
      input.attr('list', '');
  } else {
      input.attr('list', datalist);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="myList" data-list="myList">

<datalist id="myList">
  <option value="option 1">
  <option value="option 2">
</datalist>
```

Comment: On chrome on my smartphone it is triggered directly

Comment: You really don't need the `data-list`. it's very redundant. simply add/remove a single, known, character to `list` attribute to show/hide the datalist

Comment: Firefox does not show the `datalist` until the `backspace` key is pressed (for some reason)

Comment: but the problem is datalist is not closing after selecting